# WinJS listView ListLayout only selecting first row

Tags: javascript, listview, winjs

I have my listview up and running. I can click on the first row and my changes occur then click again and then it changes back just the way I want. This works with single and multi select modes and any of the usable tapBehaviors. I can select different rows in directSelect and they will select but every time I click the changes only affect the first row. I am using a ListTemplate and an ItemInvokedHandler to get things working. Here is the invoked handler:

```js
            var listview = document.querySelector('#myNote').winControl;

            listview.addEventListener("iteminvoked", itemInvokedHandler, false);

            function itemInvokedHandler(e) {

                e.detail.itemPromise.done(function (invokedItem) {

                    var whatItis = whatitis

                    if (whatItis === "whatItshouldNOTBe") {

                        var whatItshouldbe = (function () {
                            whatitis
                        })();


                    } else {

                        var whatItshouldNOTbe= (function () {
                            whatItShouldNOTBe

                        })();

                    }

                });
            };
```

Stepping through the program I find that the eventObject(e) does contain the data for all three rows that are selectable it is a matter of invoking these rows that I can not figure out.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

-Rob0

Comment: I will note that I am not using Pages or Navigator.js.

Comment: invokedItem is changing with click selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer:

```js
WinJS.Binding.as(document.querySelector(".win-selected").style.height = "70px");
```

I was not getting the exact (or being precise enough) element with my querySelector. Checking the DOM as it changed help me see this.

I realize that my original code up above is probably to sparse to really be of any help.

**--------UpDate----------**
As a note:

When using:

```js
WinJS.Binding.as(document.querySelector(".win-selected").style.height = "70px");
```

to be more precise use the ID of the element that you want to affect like this:

```js
WinJS.Binding.as(document.querySelector(".win-selected #yourElementID").style.height = "70px");
```

-Rob0